# strange character is output to the terminal

Tags: c, linux, string, terminal

I'm beginer in C/C++ programming.
This is my program that displays binary numbers in ascending order in the terminal (I'm compiling in Linux Mint).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char *x, int begin, int end)
{
   char c;

   if (begin >= end)
      return;

   c          = *(x+begin);
   *(x+begin) = *(x+end);
   *(x+end)   = c;

   reverse(x, ++begin, --end);
}


int main()
{
    unsigned int bitCount;
    unsigned int naborCount;

    printf("Число битов в наборе: ");
    scanf("%d", &bitCount);
    printf("\n");

    naborCount = pow(2, bitCount);

    char naborStr[bitCount*2];

    for(int i = 0; i<naborCount; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<bitCount; j++)
        {
            if((i & (1<<j))==0)
            {
                strcat(naborStr, "0 ");
            }
            else
            {
                strcat(naborStr, "1 ");
            }
            if(j == bitCount-1)
            {
                reverse(naborStr, 0, strlen(naborStr)-1);
                printf("%s \r\n", naborStr);
                memset(naborStr, 0, sizeof(naborStr));
            }
                
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

[This is what I see in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16OMF.jpg)

Where did this symbol come from? How to solve it?

Comment: This looks like C code, not C++ code.  Why is it tagged `c++`?

Comment: `strcat` needs nul-terminated arguments, otherwise its behaviour is undefined.

Comment: Sorry, fixed it

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please note [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that posting images of outputs and also posting images using external links is discouraged.

Comment: `naborStr` is initialzed only after it is used.  The memset needs to be moved to the top of the outer loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C strings are null terminated.

The %s specifier searches for a null termination.

In your case it keeps on printing until it finds one, so you get some random symbols.

Try making use of null character at the end of the string and check.

Have a look at the following implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse(char *x, int begin, int end)
{
char c;

if (begin >= end)
    return;

c          = *(x+begin);
*(x+begin) = *(x+end);
*(x+end)   = c;

reverse(x, ++begin, --end);
}


int main()
{
    unsigned int bitCount;
    unsigned int naborCount;

    printf("Число битов в наборе: ");
    scanf("%d", &bitCount);
    printf("\n");

    naborCount = pow(2, bitCount);

    char naborStr[bitCount*2 + 1]; //Increased size by 1 for null character

    for(int i = 0; i<naborCount; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<bitCount; j++)
        {
            if((i & (1<<j))==0)
            {
                strcat(naborStr, "0 ");
            }
            else
            {
                strcat(naborStr, "1 ");
            }
            if(j == bitCount-1)
            {
                reverse(naborStr, 0, strlen(naborStr)-1);
                naborStr[bitCount*2 +1] = '\0'; //Appending null character
                printf("%s \r\n", naborStr);
                memset(naborStr, 0, sizeof(naborStr));
            }
                
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I put the memset() method into the top of the outer loop, and it worked!